# What kind of oven do they use on the GBBS? When they tell the oven temperature, they follow the number with the word "fan". Is this a convection oven?

Tags: equipment

What kind of oven do they use on the Great British Baking Show? When they tell the oven temperature they follow the number with the word "fan". Is this a convection oven?

Answer (score 2):

The Great British Baking Show is actually the Great British Bake-Off, they seem to change the name when it goes onto PBS for some reason. The ovens they use are Neff "slide and hide" models with multiple settings. The fan mode **is** convection mode. If you don't have a convection mode the recommendation is to increase your temperature by 15 degrees C, or about 30 degrees F. Conversely if you have a convection oven and you want to use a non-convection recipe you'd drop the temperature by the same amount.

Comment: I have heard that the word "Bake-Off is copy righted by the Pillsbury Bake Off so the title was changed for viewing in America.